# type or namespace could not be found in xamarin.ios binding project

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

This is how my ApiDefinition.cs file (a part of it)

```
// @interface LSMAGuestUsecase : NSObject <LSMAUsecase>
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[DisableDefaultCtor]
interface LSMAGuestUsecase : ILSMAUsecase
{
```

And I am getting a build error like this

> Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LMAUsecase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anybody know how can I solve this issue? Please help me. I am very new to xamarin native.

Answer (score 0):

Before attributes you must specify namespace, and be sure that needed references and usings are assigned.

```
namespace AppName.Interfaces
{
    // @interface LSMAGuestUsecase : NSObject <LSMAUsecase>
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    [DisableDefaultCtor]
    interface LSMAGuestUsecase : ILSMAUsecase
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to eliminate this issue by removing "I" in ILSMAUsecase